# Convert XML to String in Ballerina

Tags: ballerina

I can print the XML in println(), but log does not accept xml type. 
I can also get XML values with `xml.getTextValue()`.

How can I get complete XML, `<test>myval</test>` as output string, in following example log statement?

```
function main(string... args) {

    xml a = xml `<test>myval</test>`;
    io:println(a);
    log:printInfo(a);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current log API only accepts strings. You can use `io:sprintf` function to get the complete string of the `xml` variable. Here is an example.

```
function main(string... args) {
    xml a = xml `<test>myval</test>`;
    string strValue = io:sprintf("%s", a);
    log:printInfo(strValue);
}
```